# Why are so few heliports depicted on sectionals?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter, navigation, visual-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

Pretty much every aerodrome, from an international airport to a private grass strip is depicted on a sectional chart. But there are few or no heliports shown. Why is this? Do helicopters have a separate sectional chart? It seems that even for a fixed wing pilot they would be useful as easily recognizable landmarks.

Just as a caveat, I don't have any actual paper sectionals. I am referring to what is shown at vfrmap.com. I have always presumed that their site is a good representation of the official charts, but it's possible there are things not shown online that are on the actual sectionals.

Comment: There are a few [helicopter route charts](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/vfrcharts/helicopter/) for a select few metropolis area's.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ah, thx. I've seen a "Heli Route Chart" section in the FAA sectional guide, but I wasn't sure whet they were

Comment: A helicopter route chart is specific to navigation and is intended for areas with high concentrations of helicopter traffic (urban). The primary intent of the chart is not to map landing zones, but rather depict information relevant to helicopter operations and traffic. Not every helipad will be charted on the route charts.  (If one is planning survey flights, it is advisable to reference the helicopter route charts, as there is useful information which will help in working with helicopter traffic, such as common routes, altitudes, frequencies, etc.) and of course some of the area helipads.

Answer (score 4):

I would disagree with the statement that pretty much every grass strip is charted.  This is common in CONUS, Alaska and Canada. There are at least 30 within a 10nm radius of mine which are not. The reasons for charting grass strips are usually: 
1. You are inviting people. 
2. You want to notice people that the strip is restricted. 
3. You are in an area, where charting your strip for emergency use is a public service you choose to offer. 
4. You have tenants on your strip, and you want to ease their navigation and those who may visit.

As for heliports being charted: If they are intended for public use, they frequently are.  They are also charted if they have allot of traffic (eg Hospital / EMS / police barracks). Many private helipads do not wish to invite the public, and there is no purpose in charting them.